# Create a command button and assign event to it in a program

Tags: vba, button, excel, spreadsheet

I found this code online and tweaked it a bit for my need to programmatically add a command button to a spreadsheet and assign an event to it. It works well

```
Sub AddComm_button()
  Set mybutton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
    Left:=126, Top:=96, Width:=126.75, Height:=25.5)
  mybutton.Name = "abcbutton"
  Call Modify_CommButton
End Sub

Sub Modify_CommButton()
  Dim LineNum As Long 'Line number in module
  Dim SubName As String 'Event to change as text
  Dim Proc As String 'Procedure string
  Dim EndS As String 'End sub string
  Dim Ap As String 'Apostrophe
  Dim Tabs As String 'Tab
  Dim LF As String 'Line feed or carriage return

  Ap = Chr(34)
  Tabs = Chr(9)
  LF = Chr(13)
  EndS = "End Sub"
  SubName = "Private Sub abcbutton_Click()" & LF
  Proc = Tabs & "MsgBox " & Ap & "Testing " & Ap & LF
  Proc = Proc & "End Sub" & LF
  Set ModEvent = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule
  With ModEvent
    LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
    .InsertLines LineNum, SubName & Proc & EndS  
  End With
End Sub
```

The following code appends my original program with this

```
Private Sub abcbutton_Click()
   MsgBox "Testing "
End Sub
```

and hence giving it a click event. 
How to I remove the appended part after my program is done. Right now when I run my program 
the second time, it already has the method abcbutton_Click() in it and it throws an error.

Thanks
Original Source : http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/5348a.html

Comment: Your inserted sub (and the code that creates it) has an extraneous `End If`, just FYI.

Comment: yyup fixed it. I made a mistake copying..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need to do is ensure the button is only added once.

```
Sub AddComm_button()
    Dim obj As OLEObject
    Dim fFoundIt As Boolean = False
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeOf obj.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
            If obj.Name = "abcbutton" Then
                fFoundIt = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not fFoundIt Then
       Set mybutton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1",Left:=126, Top:=96, Width:=126.75, Height:=25.5)
       mybutton.Name = "abcbutton"
       Call Modify_CommButton
    End if
End Sub
```

Also, you have a typo in your sub creation:

```
Proc = Proc & "End If" & LF
```

should be

```
Proc = Proc & "End Sub" & LF
```

**Update with method to remove the code**

```
Sub RemoveProcedure(sProcedureName As String)

    Set ModEvent = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule

    Dim wCurrLine As Integer
    Dim wFirstLine As Integer

    ' See if the method name exists
    For wCurrLine = 1 To ModEvent.CountOfLines
        Dim sCurrLine As String
        sCurrLine = ModEvent.Lines(wCurrLine, 1)
        If InStr(1, sCurrLine, sProcedureName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            wFirstLine = wCurrLine
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' If it does exist, remove it
    If wFirstLine <> 0 Then
        ' Start on the line after the first line
        For wCurrLine = wFirstLine + 1 To ModEvent.CountOfLines
            Dim sCurrLine As String
            sCurrLine = ModEvent.Lines(wCurrLine, 1)
            ' Found end sub
            If InStr(1, sCurrLine, "End Sub", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' So delete the lines
                ModEvent.DeleteLines wFirstLine, (wCurrLine + 1) - wFirstLine
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: yaa.. I edited the end if part.. The thing is that when I run the program, it appends my original code. How do I make sure that it deletes the code that it has appended when its done?

Comment: When I run the code second time, I get an error ambiguous name detected abcbutton_Click(). Thats because when the code was run Private Sub abcbutton_Click()
    MsgBox "Testing "
End If
End Sub
was appended to the code and abcbutton_Click() already existed. How do I make sure that the appended part goes away.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to remove the code programmatically, but the answer I provided makes sure it is only added 1 time. If the button already exists, then the button won't be added and the Sub won't be generated. As it is now, you are adding multiple buttons, but you can't see them because they are directly on top of each other.

Comment: Do you know if we can find and replace.. Something like With ModEvent
    LineNum = .CountOfLines - 3 (as it wrote 3 lines)
    .InsertLines LineNum, SubName & Proc & EndS  
  End With
End Sub .............. and then replace LineNum, SubName & Proc & EndS with ""

Comment: Thats because, I will have to dynamically add remove command buttons in my spreadsheet. If I have 4 buttons in first case, I might only have 2 buttons in second case. I can have a loop to create command buttons this way dynamically and assign events. but for the second case when I want only 2 buttons, I don't want the 4 that I created before to be there..

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I figured out a way to remove the code that you added a well. I have edited the question to include the sub that you need. Just pass this sub the name of your method (i.e.     RemoveProcedure("abcbutton_Click"))

Comment: You could also just add the code to its own module, and then just programmatically delete the entire module, rather than trying to find a specific line of code to delete.  This might be quite a bit cleaner in the long run.

Comment: Not to forget, the physical button also needs to be removed after its event code / module is removed.. I'll write the code for that..